# I want my python program to loop without using a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I am working on a tic tac toe game. I am done, but I want it to loop again if the user asks it. The problem is when I put it under a main function and indent it all. Some variables are no longer defined and it doesn't work! They do when it isn't under a main() function. These errors wouldn't occur. Does anyone know how to loop a program without using a function, or help fixing my code. For example:

```
def main():
    #My code here
#Ouput:
  File "CandT.py", line 205, in <module>
  main()
  File "CandT.py", line 203, in main
  run()
  File "CandT.py", line 188, in run
  runX()
  File "CandT.py", line 163, in runX
  askX()
  File "CandT.py", line 59, in askX
  check_stringX(x = s1)
  NameError: name 's1' is not defined
```

The full code is here: https://pastebin.com/iGcqGkRe

Comment: Sorry for not putting the code in the description. It was 200+ lines so I thought I'll give a link.

Comment: [mcve] please, especially __minimal__

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `while` loop like this.

```
def run()
    clear()
    #check_win() should return true if there is a winner or false if not
    while(check_win()==False): #if there is nobody win, continue this loop
        if turn == 0: # X's move
            runX()
            turn = 1 # the next turn will be O's
        elif turn == 1: # O's move
            runO()
            turn = 0 # the next turn will be O's

    #here after the loop, we check for the winner
    if(turn == 0):
        winner = O #because the last move is O's
    else:
        winner = X

def clear():
#reset all variables here

if __name__ == "__main__": #maybe you miss this line 
    while(True):
        play_again = int(input("play again? 1: OK, 0: No"))
        if play_again == 1:
            run()
        else:
            break
```

Comment: I attempted to create `while True` loop then ask an if statement to break or continue the loop, but it doesn't even ask at the end of the program. I dont understand your code though. Did you see the pastebin I linked.

Comment: I had a look at your code. My code can be the replacement for your `run()`. I'll edit my code and add some comments for you to understand it.

Comment: Thank you, but I dont need to modify the `check_win` function, I just need the program to restart at the end, if the user implies to.

Comment: Ah ok, I miss your question. I just modify the code again.

Comment: You are defining clear after you've called the function (line 2 and 18)

Comment: You need a `clear()` function to reset everything for playing again

Comment: Yes, but you are calling the function prior to definition.

Comment: No problem, because it's just the definition of the method. After `if __name__ == "__main__":` it's the main program.

Comment: Hey, is there a chance I can discord you or something to talk to you about my program.